# Optimized search bar filter in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, search

I have implemented search filter in reactjs, but whenever I add space in the string, it doesn't show the existing product also.
For eg: I have Values like: "Iphone details", "Samsung phone deatils". If I enter "Iphone", I'll get the searched string as "Iphone details", but If i hit **"space"** after "IPhone", I'll not get the "Iphone details" but will get no result found. Can anyone help me in making optimized search for my react app.

```
 const searchFilter = this.state.details.filter(
      (data) => {
        if (this.state.searchStr == null) return true;
        else if (
          data.name.includes(this.state.searchStr) ||
          data.title.includes(this.state.searchStr)
        ) {
          return data;
        }
      }
    );
```

Can anyone help me with what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing comparison between saved values and user typed value, it is good to bring them to the same level, as much as you possibly can. This means that we could run the user's search and the item's value through a few normalizers. Take a look at the following modified code:

```
const searchFilter = this.state.details.filter(
      (data) => {
        if (this.state.searchStr == null) return true;
        else if (
          data.name.toLowerCase().trim().includes(this.state.searchStr.trim().toLowerCase()) ||
          data.title.toLowerCase().trim().includes(this.state.searchStr.trim().toLowerCase())
        ) {
          return data;
        }
      }
    );
```

Functions I've added are:

```
.toLowerCase()
.trim()
```

What these do is normalize both the search input and data.name and data.title to be searched in lowercase, and trim function removes any whitespace for easier comparison.